Showing that the morphism from a curve $C$ to its Jacobian $J$ induces an isomorphism $\Gamma(J, \Omega^1_J) \rightarrow \Gamma(C, \Omega^1_C)$.
Let $C/k$ be a curve and $J$ its Jacobian. I am going through Milne's notes on Jacobian varieties, and in Proposition 2.2, he leaves it as an exercise to show that the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\Gamma(J,\Omega_J^1) @>{}>> \Gamma(C,\Omega_C^1)\\
@VVV @VVV\\
T_0(J)^\vee @>{}>> H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)^\vee
\end{CD}
commutes, and he uses this result to prove the result in the title. Here the map on the bottom is the dual of the map $H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C) \rightarrow T_0(J)$ that he provides in Proposition 2.1. Based on the location of this exercise in the text, he seems to indicate that one can show this using the universal property of the Jacobian (which he gives versions of in Theorems 1.1 and 1.2) without actually constructing the Jacobian.
My attempt: First, Theorem 2.2 says that, after choosing a point $P \in C$, there is a correspondence $\mathscr{M}^P$ between $(C,P)$ and $(J,0)$ which is universal. In the down-right direction, one starts with a 1-form in $\Gamma(J,\Omega_J^1)$, and then restricts it to the tangent space at the identity $T_0(J) = \ker(J(k[\epsilon]) \rightarrow J(k))$ to get a an element of the dual space $f \in \mathfrak{m}_0/\mathfrak{m}_0^2$. This gives an element of $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)^\vee$ through the identification in Proposition 2.1; more precisely, an element of $H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ gives rise to a line bundle $\mathscr{L}$ on $C_\epsilon: = C \times_k \text{Spec }k[\epsilon]$ by identifying $H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ with $H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C \epsilon) \hookrightarrow H^1(C_{\epsilon}, \mathcal{O}_{C_\epsilon}^\times)$ (using $\mathcal{O}_{C_\epsilon}^\times \simeq \mathcal{O}_C \oplus \mathcal{O}_C \epsilon$) which restricts to the trivial line bundle on $C$, which means by Theorem 1.2 that there is a unique map $\varphi: \text{Spec }k[\epsilon] \rightarrow J$ which sends the point to $0$ and has the property $(1 \times \varphi)^*(\mathscr{M}^P) \simeq \mathscr{L}$.
Since I will need to use the property $(1 \times \varphi)^*(\mathscr{M}^P) \simeq \mathscr{L}$ to analyze this diagram, I want to translate this to a statement about the map $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C) \rightarrow T_0(J)$. If I take $\sigma \in H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ and choose to represent it with a Cech cocycle $\sigma$ and $\mathscr{M}^P$ with a cocycle $m \in H^1(C \times J, \mathcal{O}_{C \times J}^\times)$, then we have that $(1 \times \varphi)^*(m) = \sigma$. To my understanding, the way $f \in \mathfrak{m}_0/\mathfrak{m}_0^2$ acts on $\varphi: \text{Spec }k[\epsilon] \rightarrow J$ is by sending $\varphi$ to the image of $f$ in the composition
$$\mathcal{O}_{J,0} \rightarrow k[\epsilon] \simeq k \oplus k\epsilon \rightarrow k\epsilon \simeq k.$$
And here I am stuck. I'm not sure how to say anything about how $f$ acts on $\sigma$ (or equivalently $\mathscr{L}$), which means I don't know how to describe the image of $\Gamma(J, \Omega_J^1)$ in $H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C)^\vee$ in a useful way. My vague thought is that the fact that $(1 \times \varphi)$ pulls $m$ back to $\sigma$ gives some information about the pullback $\varphi^*$, but I have not been able to make this precise.
Is there any approach to this that is better? In the notes Milne does warn that this is complicated; any ideas or starting points would be appreciated.
